# Spark 2.3.0 Read Text File With Header Option Not Working

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, header, apache-spark-sql, text-files

The code below is working and creates a Spark dataframe from a text file. However, I'm trying to use the header option to use the first column as header and for some reason it doesn't seem to be happening. I cannot understand why! It must be something stupid but I cannot solve this.

```
>>>from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>>spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Word Count")\
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")\
    .getOrCreate()
>>>df = spark.read.option("header", "true")\
    .option("delimiter", ",")\
    .option("inferSchema", "true")\
    .text("StockData/ETFs/aadr.us.txt")
>>>df.take(3)
```

Returns the following:

> [Row(value=u'Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,OpenInt'), 
>   Row(value=u'2010-07-21,24.333,24.333,23.946,23.946,43321,0'), 
>   Row(value=u'2010-07-22,24.644,24.644,24.362,24.487,18031,0')]

```
>>>df.columns
```

Returns the following:

> ['value']

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Issue**

The issue is that you are using `.text` api call instead of `.csv` or `.load`. If you read the *.text api documentation*, it says

> > `def text(self, paths):
> >             """Loads text files and returns a :class:DataFrame whose schema starts with a string column named "value", and followed by partitioned columns if there are any. Each line in the text file is a new row in the resulting DataFrame.
> >             :param paths: string, or list of strings, for input path(s).
> >             df = spark.read.text('python/test_support/sql/text-test.txt')
> >             df.collect()
> >             [Row(value=u'hello'), Row(value=u'this')]
> >             """`

**Solution using .csv**

Change the `.text` function call to `.csv` and you should be fine as

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "true") \
    .option("delimiter", ",") \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .csv("StockData/ETFs/aadr.us.txt")

df.show(2, truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+-------------------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
|Date               |Open  |High  |Low   |Close |Volume|OpenInt|
+-------------------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
|2010-07-21 00:00:00|24.333|24.333|23.946|23.946|43321 |0      |
|2010-07-22 00:00:00|24.644|24.644|24.362|24.487|18031 |0      |
+-------------------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

**Solution using .load**

`.load` would *assume the file to be of parquet format if a format option is not defined*. So you would *need a format option to be defined* as well

```
df = spark.read\
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("delimiter", ",") \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .load("StockData/ETFs/aadr.us.txt")

df.show(2, truncate=False)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('CaseStudy').getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").option("inferSchema", "true").load("file name")
df.show()
```

Comment: Format the code properly and may be add some explanation as to how it solves the original problem.