# Spark Dataframe not splitting on pipe "|" for log files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am fairly new to spark and trying to do my experiments before coming up with Streaming Spark ETL process. I have a log file that has no column headers in this format -

```
2019-08-02 00:25:59,116|10.29.2.5||unknown|||0|0|0|250|250|272||400|71b8fde0-5f8e-14a9-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|InvalidBucketName|
2019-08-02 00:26:00,302|10.29.2.6||unknown|||0|0|0|250|250|197||400|71b8fde2-5f8e-14a9-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|InvalidBucketName|
2019-08-02 00:26:04,142|10.29.2.5||unknown|||0|0|0|250|250|285||400|71b8fde4-5f8e-14a9-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|InvalidBucketName|
2019-08-02 00:26:04,254|10.1.198.43|splunk|getObject|splunk|splunk|160|0|200|696|1056|15875|ad%2Fdma%2Fe6%2F8f%2F464%7E1B6859C4-4A99-4DE3-B80D-2DC893813BFD%2F5C218CC9-77D3-4BBE-AD24-A5FB31CC56F2_DM_SplunkforPaloAltoNetworks_pan_traps%2Freceipt.json|200|71b8fde6-5f8e-14a9-8d12-54ab3a911327|64625d8ce9070fa1d91d9da44c8ce8c6|0|
2019-08-02 00:26:04,259|10.1.198.47|splunk|getObject|splunk|splunk|160|0|200|700|1060|10366|ad%2Fdma%2F6d%2F70%2F461%7E827F7E6F-7508-4E30-87A9-8BBDB5AFA944%2F5C218CC9-77D3-4BBE-AD24-A5FB31CC56F2_DM_SplunkforPaloAltoNetworks_pan_firewall%2Freceipt.json|200|71b8fde8-5f8e-14a9-8d12-54ab3a911327|11afe1e144bb29dcb14fba199fa000de|0|
```

I am using a `read.text()` method to get the dataframe (not sure if using read.textFile() returning a dataset has any advantages) -

```
val logRecordDF = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").textFile("/Users/atekade/Desktop/abc-logs/abc-request-info.log.2019-08-02.1")
```

but the datasets I am getting are like this -

```
[2019-08-02 00:00:00,359|10.29.2.6||unknown|||0|0|0|250|250|246||400|71b8f902-5f8e-14a9-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|InvalidBucketName|]
[2019-08-02 00:00:04,129|10.29.2.5||unknown|||0|0|0|250|250|279||400|71b8f904-5f8e-14a9-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|InvalidBucketName|]
[2019-08-02 00:00:05,346|10.29.2.6||unknown|||0|0|0|250|250|226||400|71b8f906-5f8e-14a9-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|InvalidBucketName|]
[2019-08-02 00:00:09,144|10.29.2.5||unknown|||0|0|0|250|250|267||400|71b8f908-5f8e-14a9-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|InvalidBucketName|]
```

I tried adding following combinations of for splits but none of them are giving me desired formatted data -

- option("sep", "[|]")
- option("sep", "|")
- option("sep", "\|")
- and same combination for "delimiter".

What am I doing wrong here? Just to provide more context here, I do not have column names to my data, so I created a customSchema with StructType and tried using that with `schema()` method while creating the dataframe, but not working either. Are there specific requirements to read API that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following approach. Thanks to both @Sagar and @Shu for this info that I need to read with csv API instead of text.

Create a custom schema -

```
val schemaString = "dttm|ip|bktownr|oper|bktnm|usr|" +
                    "reqhdr|reqbd|reshdr|resbd|totsize| " +
                    "duration|objnm|httpstts|s3reqid|etag|errcd|srcbkt"

val customSchema = StructType(
    schemaString
        .split('|')
        .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName,StringType,true))
    )
```

I got an schema like this -

```
customSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(dttm,StringType,true), StructField(ip,StringType,true), StructField(bktownr,StringType,true), StructField(oper,StringType,true), StructField(bktnm,StringType,true), StructField(usr,StringType,true), StructField(reqhdr,StringType,true), StructField(reqbd,StringType,true), StructField(reshdr,StringType,true), StructField(resbd,StringType,true), StructField(totsize,StringType,true), StructField( duration,StringType,true), StructField(objnm,StringType,true), StructField(httpstts,StringType,true), StructField(s3reqid,StringType,true), StructField(etag,StringType,true), StructField(errcd,StringType,true), StructField(srcbkt,StringType,true))
```

Not I can read file like this -

```
val reqLogDF:DataFrame = spark
                    .read
                    .format("csv")
                    .option("header", "true")
                    .option("delimiter", "|")
                    .schema(customSchema)
                    .load("/Users/atekade/Desktop/cloudian-logs/cloudian-request-info.log.2019-08-11.1")
                    .toDF
```

Output of `reqLogDF.collect.foreach(println)` -

```
[2019-08-11 00:00:03,002,10.1.198.42,splunk,getObject,splunk,splunk,160,0,55,246,461,2418,aws%2Fra%2Fdd%2F40%2F49%7E2D3930C7-6EC3-4134-8CF6-EED2B577A63B%2FB2CD75CD-EF9C-4844-BD2E-22805FEB53AA_splunk_app_aws_nobody_NSa7cd87ffa1c278dc%2Freceipt.json,404,4a4adcf6-f65b-14aa-8d12-54ab3a911327,0,NoSuchKey,null]
[2019-08-11 00:00:03,034,10.1.198.42,splunk,headObject,splunk,splunk,160,0,55,246,461,1523,aws%2Fra%2Fdd%2F40%2F49%7E2D3930C7-6EC3-4134-8CF6-EED2B577A63B%2FB2CD75CD-EF9C-4844-BD2E-22805FEB53AA_splunk_app_aws_nobody_NSa7cd87ffa1c278dc%2Freceipt.json,404,4a4adcf8-f65b-14aa-8d12-54ab3a911327,0,NoSuchKey,null]
[2019-08-11 00:00:03,043,10.1.198.42,splunk,getObject,splunk,splunk,160,0,55,246,461,1837,aws%2Fra%2Ffe%2Fe1%2F47%7E2D3930C7-6EC3-4134-8CF6-EED2B577A63B%2FB2CD75CD-EF9C-4844-BD2E-22805FEB53AA_splunk_app_aws_nobody_NSa7cd87ffa1c278dc%2Freceipt.json,404,4a4adcfa-f65b-14aa-8d12-54ab3a911327,0,NoSuchKey,null]
[2019-08-11 00:00:03,095,10.1.198.42,splunk,headObject,splunk,splunk,160,0,55,246,461,1700,aws%2Fra%2Ffe%2Fe1%2F47%7E2D3930C7-6EC3-4134-8CF6-EED2B577A63B%2FB2CD75CD-EF9C-4844-BD2E-22805FEB53AA_splunk_app_aws_nobody_NSa7cd87ffa1c278dc%2Freceipt.json,404,4a4adcfc-f65b-14aa-8d12-54ab3a911327,0,NoSuchKey,null]
[2019-08-11 00:00:03,550,10.29.2.5,null,unknown,null,null,0,0,0,250,250,26
```

Answer (score 2):

The spark.read.text reads the file in one single column, there is no way to specify delimiter now. It would read the file in *value* column.

Instead you can use

```
spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", "|").load("/FileStore/tables/logfile.txt")
```

You can also specify *schema* as well if required

It would load your file as

```
+-----------------------+-----------+------+---------+------+------+---+---+---+---+----+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+------------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+----+
|_c0                    |_c1        |_c2   |_c3      |_c4   |_c5   |_c6|_c7|_c8|_c9|_c10|_c11 |_c12                                                                                                                                                           |_c13|_c14                                |_c15                            |_c16             |_c17|
+-----------------------+-----------+------+---------+------+------+---+---+---+---+----+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+------------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+----+
|2019-08-02 00:25:59,116|10.29.2.5  |null  |unknown  |null  |null  |0  |0  |0  |250|250 |272  |null                                                                                                                                                           |400 |71b8fde0-5f8e-14a9-8d12-54ab3a911327|0                               |InvalidBucketName|null|
|2019-08-02 00:26:00,302|10.29.2.6  |null  |unknown  |null  |null  |0  |0  |0  |250|250 |197  |null                                                                                                                                                           |400 |71b8fde2-5f8e-14a9-8d12-54ab3a911327|0                               |InvalidBucketName|null|
|2019-08-02 00:26:04,142|10.29.2.5  |null  |unknown  |null  |null  |0  |0  |0  |250|250 |285  |null                                                                                                                                                           |400 |71b8fde4-5f8e-14a9-8d12-54ab3a911327|0                               |InvalidBucketName|null|
+-----------------------+-----------+------+---------+------+------+---+---+---+---+----+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+------------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+----+
```

Comment: But if I am looking for DF or DS in return, how do I convert this?

Comment: ohh I got it. I can just use toDF or to DS call on this. But then can this work in streaming application?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading file as [`text`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471192/spark-2-3-0-read-text-file-with-header-option-not-working) Try to read the file using `.csv` api (to split the file using some delimiter) and add your schema to the `dataframe`!

```
spark.read.option("sep","|").csv("<file_path>").show(false)
```

**`Example:`**

```
val str=Seq(("2019-08-02 00:25:59,116|10.29.2.5||unknown|||0|0|0|250|250|272||400|71b8fde0-5f8e-14a9-8d12-54ab3a911327|0|InvalidBucketName|")).toDS

spark.read.option("sep","|").csv(str).show(false)

//(or)

spark.read.option("delimiter","|").csv(str).show(false)
```

**`Result:`**

```
-----------------------+---------+----+-------+----+----+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+------------------------------------+----+-----------------+----+
|_c0                    |_c1      |_c2 |_c3    |_c4 |_c5 |_c6|_c7|_c8|_c9|_c10|_c11|_c12|_c13|_c14                                |_c15|_c16             |_c17|
+-----------------------+---------+----+-------+----+----+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+------------------------------------+----+-----------------+----+
|2019-08-02 00:25:59,116|10.29.2.5|null|unknown|null|null|0  |0  |0  |250|250 |272 |null|400 |71b8fde0-5f8e-14a9-8d12-54ab3a911327|0   |InvalidBucketName|null|
+-----------------------+---------+----+-------+----+----+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+------------------------------------+----+-----------------+----+
```

Comment: I don't understand. This is giving me an Unit and not the dataframe or dataset. If I am looking forward to convert these steps for streaming app, would I be able to use it to write these lines into some object store like S3?

Comment: Can I convert this into a dataframe?

Comment: I got it. I can just use toDF call at the end and this will work. Would the same thing work for streaming application as well?